# cross domain localhost:port request denied with $http angularjs request to web api

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

angular js hosted by ASP.NET server.
Making call to web api.
when do POST web api without parameter then works. But when pass paramter to POST web api then, it gives below error.
Error:
`XMLHttpRequest` cannot load `http://localhost:60117/api/Parts`. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin `http://localhost:64658` is therefore not allowed access.

Note: have already enabled cors nuget.  `[EnableCors("*", "*", "*")]`
below code in `webapiconfig.cs`

```
var cors = new System.Web.Http.Cors.EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);
```

Following is my request header:

```
OPTIONS /api/Parts HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:60117
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://localhost:64658
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36    (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:64658/app/views/Index.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

when do below code in web.config then, giving mulitple accept verb error.

```
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <clear/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Expose-Headers " value="WWW-Authenticate"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="accept, authorization, Content-Type"/>
        <remove name="X-Powered-By"/>
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

**Updated:**

```
Now getting below request response message:
```

`The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'.`

AJAX call:

```
$http({
        method: "POST",                       
        url: config.APIURL + 'Parts',
        data: {'final':'final'}                       
});
```

Please help me here. stuck with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

A difference in port is treated as a cross domain (xdomain) request, and as such some browsers send preflight OPTIONS request.

You will need to setup your server to accept those request and return `200 OK`
as per following url

http://enable-cors.org/server_aspnet.html

Comment: Have already enable core in webapiconfig as well as enablecores at controller level. though no luck.

Comment: you are missing the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, maybe add the request response so we can give you a better answer, I see that the config code is commented out - `<!-- -->` I hope in reality you removed the comments

Comment: have set web.config with system.webserver - `<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />`now getting error: Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Comment: The error tells you exactly what to do, you need to remove the `Content-Type` header for the `OPTIONS` call

Comment: I have removed content type. edited question with ajax call request. but getting same.`Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight respo`

Comment: 'Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://localhost:64658' is therefore not allowed access.' this error is coming now.

Comment: `Access-Control-Request-Headers:content-type` that's the wrong header for request

Comment: I am not setting that. I have set content type- 'application/json'  and also checked by removing. searched in web api and angular js both but not found it. Facing thie error: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/SigmaNest.WebAPI/api/Parts. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://localhost:64658, *', but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://localhost:64658' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: Hi now getting error: `The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'.`. have also added httppost attribute. have updated question - with all request, response details.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't succeeded in your attempts, you can try this.
   In your Globax.asax of your WebApi, have the following method

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
        {
            if (Context.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
            {
                Context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", Context.Request.Headers["Origin"]);
                Context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
                Context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");                    
                Context.Response.End();
            }
    }
```

And In your WebApi Config Have the following method call to enable cors

```
  config.EnableCors();
```

And in your controller(s) have attribute similar to

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

Hope this helps.
You can also refer this site https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn532203.aspx for additional details.
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You need to add `CorsMessageHandler` class on server side for allowing HTTP request.